# js-ipfsを用いてコンテンツのアップロード

Tags: javascript, ipfs

js-ipfsを用いてコンテンツの内容をIPFSネットワークにアップロードさせたいです。
コンテンツに対応するCID取得まではうまくいったと思うのですが、そのCIDに対応するkeyの作成方法と、それらをDHTに追加しようとしてもうまくいかないです。
どのようにしたら良いでしょうか？
下記がコードになります。

```
const ipfs = await IPFS.create()
const { cid } = await ipfs.add('これがアップロードしたいコンテンツの内容です。スタックオーバーフローっっっd')
console.info("ku"+cid+"ku")
this.cid = cid

// CIDからKeyを作成する
const key = cid.toBytes()

// DHTにエントリを追加する
await ipfs.dht.put(key, cid.bytes)
```